# Handle zip file in ashx file

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I uploaded one zip file using file upload control in Asp.net and after submitting the button I need to send that file to an ashx handler.In handler I need to receive the file as it is and save that file to a location.How to achieve that

Comment: Do you want to store the zip-file as-is, or unzipped? What do you have so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

To save the file, you will have to use the [Request.Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx) collection.

```
foreach (string file in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFile zipFile = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;
    if (zipFile.ContentLength > 0)
       zipFile.SaveAs("YOUR_PATH/" + file);
}
```

If you need to extract the contents of the zip file, you can use a library like [dotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)